# Perl DBI where IS NULL with undefined variable

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have a `perl` `DBI` `mysql` query that looks like this:

```
my $rows = get_rows(
    "select id from table where column1=?, column2=? and column3=?",
    $var1,$var2,$var3
    );

sub get_rows {

    my $sql = shift;
    my @vars = @_;      
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(@vars);
    my $rows = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();
    $sth->finish();         
    return $rows;
    }
```

I'm running this to check if a particular row exists containing those vars. The problem I have however is with dealing with NULL values. These have to be selected as `IS NULL` rather than `=?`, which very often then misses rows that contain NULL values. For example, if vars 1, 2 and 3 contain `'12'`, `'23'` and `undef` and `table` contains `12`, `23` and `NULL` then the query returns no results. Is there a simple way to transform undef values into `IS NULL` values with `DBI`?

Comment: Your whole `get_rows` function could be replaced by DBI's `selectall_hashref` method.

Comment: @simbabque, you meant `selectall_arrayref`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented in [DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI) under *NULL Values*.

```
$sql_clause = defined $age? "age = ?" : "age IS NULL";
$sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{
  SELECT fullname FROM people WHERE $sql_clause
});
$sth->execute(defined $age ? $age : ());
```

Comment: Thanks. Had not seen this. I've ended up modifying the query rather than the code as was one of the suggestions on the DBI documentation.